# Draggable jQuery element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement the drag-around thing from W3schools to my js file.

Here's the link to the drag-around thing I'm referring to.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable

Below is my js file that makes a div and implemented the drag-around thing from w3schools.

first.js

```
function makediv() {
        var mydiv= document.createElement('div')
        mydiv.style = "resize: both; overflow: auto; width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 2px solid black; "
        mydiv.id = "mydiv"

        var innerdiv= document.createElement('div')
        innerdiv.id = "innerdiv"
        innerdiv.style = "resize: both; overflow: auto; width: 250px; height: 250px; border: 2px solid black; "
        
        
        mydiv.appendChild(innerdiv);

        const body= document.querySelector('body') 
        body.appendChild(mydiv);

}

//W3school stuff
function dragElement(element) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  
  document.getElementById(element.id).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    console.log("e");//I'm console.log the event to check whether the function is called
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    console.log(e.clientX);
    console.log(e.clientY);
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    console.log("dragging")//I'm console.log the event to check whether the function is called
    console.log(e)
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    element.style.top = (element.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call the above functions from another js file. And my problems begin here.

second.js

```
makediv()
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
```

I can see all the logs showing the events and "dragging"s when I mousedown on the div and try to drag around the div. But the div is not moving as I'm dragging it and it's not dropped to the location where I mouseup.

**by logs, I mean I placed some console.log in first.js's W3schools part to check whether the functions are working. I marked these console.log calls by //I'm console.log the event to check whether the function is called

I really don't get it, as the logs show that dragMouseDown and elementDrag are working, but the div is actually not being dragged.

Below is my html file:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>testing</title>

    <script defer type="text/javascript" src='first.js'></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src='second.js'></script>

 </head>
 <body>

 </body>

</html>
```

My ultimate goal is to make the first js file working as a library while not using other 3rd party libraries like jqueryui. But I got stuck here, that mydiv is not being draggable.

I'm kind of new to js and html. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply that you missed a CSS property which is `position: absolute`, just add it back.

```
mydiv.style = "resize: both; overflow: auto; width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 2px solid black; position: absolute"
```